# Do I have to create an object to call on class methods, or can I just type in the class name?

Tags: c++, object

Note - I'm new and this is my first question on S.Overflow.

I'm testing the limitations and am trying to more clearly understand all of this programming syntax.

When I try to build and run this, it won't work. Why make an object when I can just type in the class name?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Sayings{
    public:
        void coolSaying(){
            cout << "Preachin to the choir" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{

Sayings.coolSaying();


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a static method if you don't want to instantiate an object.  However, the advantages of having an object instance means you can create more than one instance of the same class with different data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Sayings{
    public:
        static void coolSaying(){
            cout << "Preachin to the choir" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{    
    Sayings::coolSaying();    
}
```

And as an sample of the usefulness of class instances:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Sayings{
    public:
        Sayings(const std::string & saying) : saying_(saying) {
        }

        void coolSaying(){
            cout << saying_ << endl;
        }
    private:
        std::string saying_;
};

int main()
{    
    Sayings s1("Preachin to the choir");
    Sayings s2("Cool story bro");

    s1.coolSaying();
    s2.coolSaying();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must have an instance of a class in order to call its non-static member functions. If you want to call members without having an instance of the class they must be declared as static.

```
class Sayings
{
    public:
        // static member function. Can be called without having an instance
        // of Sayings
        static void coolSaying()
        {
            cout << "Preachin to the choir" << endl;
        }

        // non-static member function. Requires an instance of Sayings
        // to be called.
        void anotherCoolSaying()
        {
            cout << "Preachin to the pulpit" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Sayings::coolSaying();

    Sayings s;
    s.anotherCoolSaying();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for needing an instance of the class is well, if the class has "state". A class has state if it has member variables that change over time, then you would need an instance of that class in order to call the (non-static) member functions. On the other hand if the class is stateless (or if the method does not affect the state of the objects of that class, meaning it doesn't change the member variables) then you can make it a static member function. Static member functions do not require an instance of the class in order to be called.

```
#include <iostream>

class Widget
{
public:
    Widget(): x(0) {} // constructor with initialization list
    void setX(int newVal) { x = newVal; } // changes the state of an instance
    void printX() { std::cout << x << std::endl; } // interacts with the state of an instance

    static void printClassName() { std::cout << "Widget" << std::endl; } // doest change or interact with the state therefore can be made static
private:
    int x;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Widget w;
    w.printX();
    w.setX(4);
    w.printX();
    Widget::printClassName();
    //w::printX(); <-- this won't compile because it is not static

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see [here](https://ideone.com/qPjgBg), the output is:
0
4
Widget

Answer (score 0):

Non-static class member functions are called with an object of the class using the dot operator `.`Therefore you need to first create an object of the class using proper constructor of the class:

```
Sayings s; //create an object of class using default constructor
s.coolSaying(); //call methods
```

static member functions are called with class name followed by the scope resolution operator `::`:

```
Sayings::coolSaying(); //For this to work you need the following:

class Sayings{
public:
   static void coolSaying(){
   //^^^
        cout << "Preachin to the choir" << endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way... would it make sense to have a function modify data if that data wouldn't exist?  As other have mentioned, if you want a function just to do stuff unrelated to the class's member variables, a viable option would be to just use a static method.

Another option is to just write the function outside of the class completely if it doesn't not interact with the class at all.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from C++ Standard

`A non-static member function may be called for an object of its class type, or for an object of a class derived (clause 10)
from its class type, using the class member access syntax (5.2.5, 13.3.1.1). A non-static member function may also be
called directly using the function call syntax.`